# Is there any way to manually fold code in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, folding

Is there any way to manually create fold points in code in Eclipse? I know how to enable folding and how to set the auto preferences, but i like being able to set my own fold points so I can ignore certain parts of my code. Think regions in VS.
 I know there is in VS and NetBeans, but I cannot find a way to set manual fold  points in Eclipse.

Comment: Check (and vote ) : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=63808

Comment: Coffee-Bytes for Eclipse 3.6 & higher: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think Eclipse has built in manual folding, but I did use a previous version of the following plugin for it.

Per the comment: The plugin has been recompiled for Eclipse 3.5 and is available at [the Apache Isis site](http://incubator.apache.org/isis/ide-support.html). A [direct download link](http://incubator.apache.org/isis/com.cb.eclipse.folding.KAM-3.5.zip) is also available. It also appears to work for Eclipse 3.6.

Comment: No longer available for down-load. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Thanks, don't have svn and don't have time to set it up. I'll survive without the code folding

Comment: General note for anyone reading this: The plugin has been recompiled for Eclipse 3.5 and is available at http://nakedobjects.org/com.cb.eclipse.folding.KAM-3.5.zip at the time of writing this. It also appears to work for Eclipse 3.6.

Comment: How to configure & use the 'KAM' plugin, in Eclipse 3.6? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The coffee bytes folding plug-in for eclipse is still alive. But the pages have moved.

An Overview and how to get it can be found [here](http://archive.realjenius.com/platform_support).

I've installed it in eclipse using the update page.

In Eclipse go to Help -> Install new Software
Enter: eclipse.realjenius.com/update-site
Select the plugin and follow on-screen instruction.

I'm still pretty new to eclipse development and had to install mylyn before installing the code folding plugin.

Comment: The URL is dead, but the Google code page is still about: http://code.google.com/p/coffee-bytes/

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Eclipse, but since the IDE lets you fold preprocessor directives, you can just do "#if 1 .... #endif" to effectively set up manual folding.

Comment: It does not support this for Java.

Answer (score 1):

No, eclipse does not have any option to provide manual folding plugins.