# How to use Coffee-Bytes code folding

Tags: eclipse, folding

How to use "[Coffee-Bytes code folding](http://market.eclipsesource.com/yoxos/node/com.cb.eclipse.folding.feature.group)"?
I want to use user defined region but don't know how to use it.
Can anyone guide me? And how to use it in java code?

Comment: [Coffee-Bytes for Eclipse 3.6 & higher][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6

Comment: So... I see the link you posted -- and it has a great description and all -- but how the heck do you download it?!

Comment: For reference, the download location is buried in the answers comments somewhere: http://kosiara87.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html -- Also, this appears to work in Luna, but you have to restart once after installing, and once again after configuring.

Comment: I created an update site for the old coffee bytes code folding plugin that works with Eclipse Neon:
https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding/raw/master/com.cb.platsupp.site

Answer (score 51):

Firstly, you'll need to configure Coffee Bytes Java folding as the folding scheme to use, and then enable User Defined Regions, as shown below.

[image: Enable Coffee Bytes Java folding]

Secondly, you'll need to configure the start and end identifiers that will be used to identify the beginning and termination of regions in your code. In this case, I've chosen `{{` and `}}` as it fits well with the Apache Isis templates that I use.

[image: Configure the start and end regions]

Finally, I use the same start and end identifiers in my code to demarcate regions and to trigger the Coffee Bytes folding plugin to recognize the same.  After saving the preferences, your user-defined regions should immediately take effect (although you may need to close and re-open any open code files).

[image: Use start and end regions in code]

Comment: I've never seen CoffeeBytes Code Folder before. Could you perhaps include how to acquire/install it?

Comment: @Patrick, there's a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206158/is-there-any-way-to-manually-fold-code-in-eclipse) that answers your question. Also, check the [Apache Isis site](http://incubator.apache.org/isis/ide-support.html).

Comment: Coffee-Bytes does not work in Eclipse 3.6:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/any-good-code-folding-plugin-for-eclipse-3-6-the-coffee-bytes-code-folding-does

Comment: Read the comment 3 above you - Apache Isis has a Coffee-Bytes that works for 3.6.

Comment: +1, this work and working Coffee-byte for Eclipse Indigo is here http://kosiara87.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html

Comment: I would love to be able to just highlight an arbitrary block of text and say "fold this" without having to edit the code.  The folding doesn't need to persist between loads or anything.  I *still* haven't found a way to do this in Eclipse, although Vim has had it for years...

Comment: Hmmm... didn't work right away in Eclipse Luna -- after configuring the options I had to close and re-open it.

Comment: @VineetReynolds your link is broken.

Comment: Ehhh..   Cannot get user-defined regions to fold in MyEclipse v.10.   The minus sign does not pop up after I add the comment lines with start and end identifiers..