# create collapsible code block eclipse

Tags: eclipse

To make my code clean and tidy on eclipse, I wonder if it is feasible to code surrounded by Any tag to be able to retract as a function.
I use eclipse "Juno" for android development.

Comment: Incidentally, I know Colmar well ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use the plugin "[**Coffee Bytes Code Folding**](http://market.eclipsesource.com/yoxos/node/com.cb.eclipse.folding.feature.group)".
With Indigo or Juno, you might need to grab the latest version of that plugin at "[this page](http://kosiara87.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html)" (or google "`com.cb.eclipse.folding_1.0.7.jar`" for Juno-compatible version).

You will find all the illustrations in the SO question: "[How to use Coffee-Bytes code folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940199/how-to-use-coffee-bytes-code-folding)":

[image: custom folding region]

Comment: @VonC thanks dear for such a nice info (Y) well i am using ECLIPSE KEPLAR for that i ve downloaded `com.cb.eclipse.folding_1.0.7.jar` its working for me.. any body can download `plugin` from [here](http://kosiara87.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html) and for `com.cb.eclipse.folding_1.0.7.jar` it can be downloaded from [here](http://www.bergfiles.com/i/bf5773d50eh32i0)

Comment: the link to download is not working at this moment. If somebody has an idea where to find this nice feature, please let us know. Thanks.