# Coffe Bytes Java Folding

Tags: java, eclipse-juno, code-folding

I recently downloaded Coffe Bytes for Eclipse Juno and followed this tutorial to install

[How to use Coffee-Bytes code folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940199/how-to-use-coffee-bytes-code-folding)

but when I do somthing like the following

```
// {{ fold block
public static void stuffToFold()
{
   return 4;
}
// }}
```

It does not allow me to fold that fold block

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it working, all you need to do is add

`// }} fold block`

instead of the

`// }}`

line that you have in your code.