# User defined folding regions in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, folding, code-folding

Does anyone know of any up to date plugins that will allow for custom folding regions in eclipse and are working on 4.5, Mars. Lots of old posts talk about Coffe Beans however I have been unable to get that working with eclipse Mars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What code folding plugins work on Eclipse 3.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? Supposedly it [works on Luna](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940199/how-to-use-coffee-bytes-code-folding#comment41081772_6940199).

Comment: Using Mars, version 4.5 I believe. Will try getting it working on Luna tomorrow when I'm on the pc