# How to fold if/else sub blocks in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, if-statement, ide, fold

Though I have looked at these two questions, [fold sub blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2369057/1626878) and [manually fold code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206158/1626878).

But it doesnt seems to work, because either the links are broken or some of the resources are unavailable.

In my project, I have lot of functions, which include literally millions of `if/else` statements. Now, whenever I have to look for a `Log`, I have to shuffle the entire code. Most of the time is wasted in the `if/else` code blocks. It would be really helpfull, if I could fold these `if/else` sub blocks. There is no inbuilt feature in eclipse though. Is there any plugin that could help for the purpose.

Comment: Just see this [Collapsing codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726525/is-there-a-way-to-collapse-all-code-blocks-in-eclipse).


Also this [Doc](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Folding-in-Eclipse-Text-Editors/folding.html) helps you

Comment: not exactly.:D but it seems like I'm traversing millions when I have to search for a log every 5 minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to fold eclipse sub-blocks like an "if" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369057/is-there-a-way-to-fold-eclipse-sub-blocks-like-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Preferences  ->  Java  -> Editor -> Folding.

Set folding settings here by checking the boxes as your need..

Comment: I only see options for 1) Folding enabled, 2) which things are initially folded. Nothing to enable specific types of folding. Am I missing something? Thanks :)

Comment: Folding of if/else sub blocks for Java does not work in Eclipse, not even 7 years later, in 2019. There might be plugins that do that.