# Fold highlighted text in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How do I fold the text block I highlighted in eclipse (preferably if there is a key shortcut)? I am certain it is possible (because basically everything is possible with eclipse), I'm just unaware of how to fold anything that is not a function (which comes automatically).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206158/is-there-any-way-to-manually-fold-code-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, folding depends on the kind of editor your are using (Java, C/C++, JSP...).
Anyway, to my knowledge, such a fine folding ability isn't available (in Juno) for the editors I have given as example.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505413/code-folding-in-eclipse) you can find a similar question and the answers that were given.